# How to connect Azure Scheduler programmatically using .NET

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, scheduler

I'm trying to connect my Azure Scheduler via my .Net Application however, at the current state I'm getting `KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

I have tried to example in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/scheduler-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/SchedulerArmSDKTemplate

The problem with the above example is, I think it is based on previous version of the packages. So on the latest version, I tried to make it work by myself but I wasn't able to. The amount of documentation around this and AD Connect is really limited, especially when it comes to new Portal and latest versions. My code sample is below, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point:

```
var tenantId = "{tenantId}"; // I have put objectId from Azure AD Properties
var clientId = "{clientId}"; // Here, I have created new App Registration in Azure AD and copied the AppId value
var subscriptionId = "{subscriptionId}"; //Subscription Id of the scheduler resource

UserLoginInformation loginInformation = new UserLoginInformation()
{
    ClientId = clientId
};
ServiceClientCredentials serviceClientCredentials = new AzureCredentials(loginInformation, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

SchedulerManagementClient schedulerManagementClient =
            new SchedulerManagementClient(serviceClientCredentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

var schedulers = await schedulerManagementClient.JobCollections.GetWithHttpMessagesAsync("{resourceGroup}", "{jobCollectionName}");
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Tennat Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-howto-tenant#use-an-msa-azure-subscription)** is **not** the application **objectid**. We could get it from the Azure portal, more detail please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

If user is not required **multi-factor** authentication. please have a try to use the following code.

```
var tenantId = "tenantId"; // Not the object id, it is Azure directory Id
var clientId = "client Id"; // Here, I have created new App Registration in Azure AD and copied the AppId value
var subscriptionId = "subscription Id"; //Subscription Id of the scheduler resource
var resourceGroup = "resource group";
var jobCollectionName = "job name";
UserLoginInformation loginInformation = new UserLoginInformation()
{
       ClientId = clientId,
       UserName = "xxx@example.com",
       Password = "xxxxxx"
};
ServiceClientCredentials serviceClientCredentials = new AzureCredentials(loginInformation, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

SchedulerManagementClient schedulerManagementClient =
                new SchedulerManagementClient(serviceClientCredentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

var schedulers =  await schedulerManagementClient.JobCollections.GetWithHttpMessagesAsync($"{resourceGroup}", $"{jobCollectionName}");
```

Comment: I meant the DirectoryId buy objectId of AD and not for the application. Sorry, I wasn't clear.

Comment: According to the error info you mentioned `KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`  I  assume that is not related to you mentioned code. Please have a try to create a new  C# console project with the code mentioned and test it again. I registry a native Azure  AD application, it works on my side.

Comment: I have tried both native and web/api application, but still getting same error. Also tried to adding username and password of my user in the azure, which is in owner role, still no luck